# Is it bad practice to bind a view directly to a service property?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a chat service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {    
    private state: ChatState = {
        loading: true,
        unseenMessages: false,
        chatGroups: []
    };

    getState(){
       return this.state; 
    }

    .... 
}
```

Now I want to use the "unseenMessages" parameter to make badge in my main nav:

```
export class MainNavComponent implements OnInit {
    chat: ChatState;

    constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.chat = this.chatService.getState();
    }
}
```

Note that this.chat is now a reference to exact same object instance as in the service, so now I can use it is my view like:

```
    <div class="chat" (click)="onChat()">
        <img *ngIf="!chat.loading" src="..."/>
        <div *ngIf="chat.unseenMessages" class="batch"></div>
        <div *ngIf="chat.loading" class="la-ball-clip-rotate  la-sm ">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And still keep change detection etc. intact. So when I change the state inside the service, the view will update accordingly.

I know that Angular is big on observables, so my question is if this way is bad practice? Are there any down sides compared to observables in this scenario?

**One problem** I have at the moment that might relate to this is, that when I clear the "unseenMessages" flag inside the service, I get a "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError". in the MainNacComponent. There's of course ways of fixing this, but it led me to, that it might be bad practice.

Comment: in short, yes. It can reduce your program's flexibility to adapt to future changes. Service properties are mean to be live longer than the instance of the view. Clear segregation among them will help your code clean and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem using service like that in a component view.
I use it all the time myself and its very convenient.
I have a service which has many common properties like "asOfDate" or alike and shadowing them would be a lot of extra coding and unnecessary effort.
I use it exactly the same: in constructor I get it either private or public (depending on usage) and in view bind to that service directly.
Didn't see problems neither how it works nor when I need to do code refactoring, the latter is even easier to do.